# template accept both throw and nothrow with one specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want to write a template class `MyClass` that accept both normal and noexcept signature. For example `MyClass<int()>` and `MyClass<int() noexcept>`.

This is what I have tried:

```
template<typename TSignature>
struct IsNoThrow;

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...)> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template<typename T, bool = IsNoThrow<T>::value>
class MyClass;


template<bool BNoThrow, typename TReturn, typename...TParams>
class MyClass<TReturn(TParams...) noexcept(BNoThrow), BNoThrow> {
    //VS2017(/std:c++latest) gives error C2057: expected constant expression
};


int main() {
    MyClass<int()> mc;
}
```

Why I got that error C2057? How can I do it without specializing `MyClass` twice like I did with `IsNoThrow`?

Comment: MSVC doesn't support C++17 fully yet. I don't think you have any recourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I got that error C2057? How can I do it without specializing MyClass twice like I did with IsNoThrow?

I suppose the error is a VC bug but, anyway, your solution seems overcomplicated to me.

I propose

(1) inheritance, for `IsNoThrow`, from `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` (to simplify and use facilities in `std::integral_constant`)

```
template<typename TSignature>
struct IsNoThrow;

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...)> : public std::false_type
 { };

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

or, maybe, simpy

```
template<typename TSignature>
struct IsNoThrow;

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs, bool B>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept(B)> : public std::integral_constant<bool, B>
 { };
```

(2) if your aren't interested in return-type and argument type of function (but only in intercepting functions and detecting if they are throwing or no-throwing)  only a main class/struct for `MyClass` (no specialization) that inherit from `IsNoThrow`

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass : public IsNoThrow<T>
{ };
```

This way `MyClass` compile only if the `T` type is a function type (`MyClass<int>` gives compilation error) and inherit from `std::true_type` or from `std::false_type` according `noexcept` value.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TSignature>
struct IsNoThrow;

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...)> : public std::false_type
 { };

template<typename TReturn, typename...TArgs>
struct IsNoThrow<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept> : public std::true_type
 { };

template<typename T>
struct MyClass : public IsNoThrow<T>
 { };

int foo (int)
{ return 0; }

int bar (int) noexcept
{ return 0; }

int main()
 {    
   static_assert( false == MyClass<decltype(foo)>::value );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<decltype(bar)>::value );
   static_assert( false == MyClass<int(int)>::value );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<int(int) noexcept>::value ); 

   //MyClass<int> mc; // compilaton error
 }
```

If you're interested in return and argument types, it seems to me that you need a specialization and a possible solution is

```
template<typename T>
struct MyClass;

template<typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs, bool B>
struct MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept(B)> : public std::integral_constant<bool, B>
 { };
```

**-- EDIT --**

If your VC compiler doesn't support C++17 at point of deduce the boolean value in `noexcept(B)`, I suppose that (given that you need to deduce also return and arguments types) you need two `MyClass` specialization.

But if your problem is that you have to duplicate the content of this specialization, I propose a two-specialization solution where the second one inherit from the first one:

```
template<typename T, bool = false>
struct MyClass;

template<typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs, bool B>
struct MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...), B> : public std::integral_constant<bool, B>
 { /* all common member/methods here */ };

template<typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs>
struct MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept> 
    : public MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...), true>
 { /* empty: inherhit all from the other specialization */ };
```

This way you don't need `IsNoThrow` and you can develop only the first one specialization: all member and methods in it are inherited from the other specialization.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, bool = false>
struct MyClass;

template<typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs, bool B>
struct MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...), B> : public std::integral_constant<bool, B>
 { 
   /* all common member/methods here */

   static constexpr bool isNoExcept ()
    { return B; }
 };

template<typename TReturn, typename ... TArgs>
struct MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...) noexcept> 
    : public MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...), true>
 { /* empty: inherhit all from the other specialization */ };

int foo (int)
{ return 0; }

int bar (int) noexcept
{ return 0; }

int main()
 { 
   // using value 
   static_assert( false == MyClass<decltype(foo)>::value );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<decltype(bar)>::value );
   static_assert( false == MyClass<int(int)>::value );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<int(int) noexcept>::value ); 

   // using isNoExcept() 
   static_assert( false == MyClass<decltype(foo)>::isNoExcept() );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<decltype(bar)>::isNoExcept() );
   static_assert( false == MyClass<int(int)>::isNoExcept() );
   static_assert( true  == MyClass<int(int) noexcept>::isNoExcept() ); 

   //MyClass<int> mc; // compilaton error
 }
```

Comment: sadly MyClass needs to know the return type and all the parameter types

Comment: @JohnSmith - so you need a specialization... give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: @JohnSmith - answer improved.

Comment: I got a `error C2764: 'B': template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization MyClass<TReturn(TArgs...)>`. The error don't even have `noexcept(B)` in it. maybe I should wait until c++17 is fully supported in VS.

Comment: @JohnSmith - yes... I suppose it's a problem of C++17 support; anyway, have you tried if works the no-return-and-arg-types version? Just to know if my version of `IfNoThwow` works in VC and if is the case of imagine something different.

Comment: I think that should works. They half supported this feature, quite annoying. I end up with two specialization and it works fine.

Comment: @JohnSmith - so dou you think should work the `std::true_type`/`std::false_type` variant but not the `std::integral_constant` one?

Comment: Of course. VS recognize that `MyClass<int(int)>` and `MyClass<int(int) noexcept>` are two different types. But it can't deduce the constant `B`.

Comment: @JohnSmith - I see... so I suppose that are strictly necessary two `MyClass` specializations: the `noexcept` and the not-`noexcept` one. If this is a problem for you because you have to duplicate the code in specializations, you can try to inherit one from the another.

Comment: @JohnSmith - answer improved (added another example) in case your problem is the code duplication in two specializations.